# Crystal report licencing with vs 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, licensing

If I sell my application which is develop in VS 2008 which contains some crystal reports too then

- Do I need a Crystal Reports license?
- If Yes then what would be the price?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1):

Crystal Reports licensing can indeed be very complex.

The general rule seems to be that:

- the runtime is royalty-free if the user can only view reports in thick client applications running on his desktop
- as soon as the user can modify reports in your application, you have to pay
- if the application is run as a server application, on a terminal server or as web server application, you have to pay

More information can be found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317789

Answer (score 1):

SAP (which now owns Business Objects) has a **free** SAP Crystal Report Viewer.

http://www.sap.com/solutions/sap-crystal-solutions/query-reporting-analysis/sapcrystalreports/index.epx

You should browse the SAP website for the answer to your question or just call them directly (the sales people are quick to answer your call, but very aggressive too).
1-800-877-2340